# What's the difference between various usage of NFS storage

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

My customer asked me about if there is any difference when using NFS as the following:  
Method1: define PV like the following:

---

apiVersion: v1  
kind: PersistentVolume  
metadata:  
  name: mysqldb-volume  
spec:  
  capacity:  
    storage: 3Gi  
  accessModes:  
  - ReadWriteMany  
  nfs:  
    path: /var/export/dbvol  
    server: master.lab.example.com

---

Method 2: mount nfs on local file system /home/myapp/dir1, and define PV like this:

---

apiVersion: v1  
kind: PersistentVolume  
metadata:  
  name: mysqldb-volume  
spec:  
  capacity:  
    storage: 1Gi  
  accessModes:  
  - ReadWriteOnce  
  hostPath:  
    path: /home/myapp/dir1

---

The pod will run a openjdk image which will output to a file on NFS, Seems both should work, is there any difference?

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 0):

doing it with hostPath requires intervention on node - pre-mounting of the NFS before you spin up pod(s), making it happen outside of in kubernetes dependencies (ie. unavailability of NFS will not hold pod startup but start it without mounted content, which is very bad).

By design the direct NFS PV is much cleaner and obvious, but in the end, both will work in general.

Comment: Thanks, understood.